# show event label with referral path in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to somehow connect/pass event variables (label, etc.) from referring site to referred site? I own both sites. I would like to create a report that shows url where the click was made and also what kind of event the link belongs to.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass referrer in event label
But in GA there exist dimensions that can show you referrers for events
Full Referrer
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_fullreferrer
&
Referral Path
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_referralpath

Comment: Hi, not sure if I understand. I would like to see in analytics report, the pages that visitor came from (this part is no problem), however, I would like to see also if there is an event attached to that click on referring site.

Comment: You can pass event name as query parameter, and then strip it using URL variable. Variable can then be used as event label. http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/#14